# Как реализовать скролл в свайпере?

Tags: javascript, swiper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
      });
```

```css
html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/7.2.0/swiper-bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/7.2.0/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так но для большой оптимизации нужно отключать на время перехода сам ивент скролла

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
slidesPerView: 3,
scrollbar: {
            el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
            draggable: true,
          },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
      });
```

```css
html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/7.2.0/swiper-bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      </div>
<div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/7.2.0/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: линии нет. В этом смысл

Comment: линии скролла. снизу

Comment: @flowers Отредачил код не увидел первый раз картинку пример

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: Скролл работает только на мобильных устройствах. И то "работает" это можно назвать с натяжкой. На десктопе скролл стоит мёртво... Ваш свайпер - полное УГ (специально для отпугивания посетителей вашего сайта пользоваться вашими услугами).

Comment: @DiD насколько я поняла, то такой скролл "вшит" в свайпер. Разве есть другой вариант?

Comment: разумеется, есть. - Не пытаться перепрограммировать скролл с помощью скриптов. Есть [scroll-snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap) [статья по scroll-snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts) [пример в работе](https://snap.glitch.me/carousel.html)

Comment: @flowers Просто кто-то управляет курсором мышкой, у кого-то тачпад, у кого-то сенсорный дисплей, а кто-то управляет стилусом, а кто-то пультом на телевизоре. А я вообще управляю курсором глазами. И еще есть много разных способов. Вы всё это спрограммируете?

Comment: @DiD   а scroll-snap разве стилизируется? или без проблем?

Comment: @DiD Можно дописать к слайдеру доп функционал например при наведении мыши на слайдер подключить скролл ивент конторый просто нажимает на кнопку next-slide или prev-slide при скролле верх-вниз это же не проблема. На счет оптимизации под каждый жест есть много библиотек у которых уже есть этот функционал и настроить его никогда не было проблемой.  scroll-snap конечно круто но он также не будет реагировать на прокрутку колеса мыши в данном слайдере проверил!

Comment: @pyduti а откуда фреймворк узнает как и чем я управляю курсором? веб-страница пока мышь от тачпада отличить не в состоянии. А работают они абсолютно по-разному. В тачпаде и инерция и горизонтальный скролл сравните тачпад с теми же Trackball.